# Open form with Form Name in winform appliaction

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, desktop-application, windows

I want to ask what should i do to open form with the help or class name in winform c#?

I have three different forms

- UserManagement
- GroupsManagement
- LocationManagement

I get permission from database for these three forms

in menu click i fill tag Property with the name of form  like this

```
tsmMain.Tag = item.PermissionName
tsmMain.Click += new EventHandler(tsmMain_Click);
```

what i want to do is to open form dynamically in button click and to remove these if condition?
Can i do this with reflection or else??

```
ToolStripMenuItem aa = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;
        var tag = aa.Tag;
        if (tag == "User Management")
        {
            UserManagement oUserForm = new UserManagement();
            oUserForm.Show();
        }
        if (tag == "Groups Management")
        {
            GroupManagement oGroupForm = new GroupManagement();
            oGroupForm.Show();
        }
```

Comment: is there any way to match `PermissionName` to the actual `Form`, like a property called `FormName` or something

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may be able to do something like this, using the name of your form, as a string argument:

```
var form = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("YourNameSpace.UserManagement"));
form.Show();
```

Answer (score 5):

One straightforward, but not necessarily very clean solution would be to store the forms right there in the `Tag` property of your menu items, rather than the strings.

Somewhere at the beginning of your application, you'd have to assign these instances:

```
myUserManagementItem.Tag = new UserManagement();
myGroupsManagementItem.Tag = new GroupManagement();
```

Then, in the click event, you could shorten your code to:

```
ToolStripMenuItem aa = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;
Form form = aa.Tag as Form;
form.Show();
```

---

Cleaner solutions would include the following:

- Provide separate event handlers for different menu items.
- Derive your own menu item types that store the form to show in a strongly-typed property.